# Least number of temporary variables required to create three address code in static single assignment form for the expression $p+q*r-s/(q*r)$

Tags: compilers

I found a question.

> Least number of temporary variables required to create three address code in static single assignment form for the expression $p+q*r-s/(q*r)$

**My attempt**:

> $t_1 = q*r$ 
>     $t_2 = s/t_1$ 
>     $t_3 = p + t_1$ 
>     $t_4 = t_3 - t_2$

So, I got $4$ variables but their answer is $5$. Am I missing something? Where I am being wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe I'm missing something as well.

Comment: Who are "they"? If you can provide an accessible source of question, this question should be simple enough to answer.

Comment: @Apass.Jack a local question from an online  test series.

Answer (score 2):

You used the optimisation of calculating q * r only once. Maybe someone considered that "cheating" and is insisting that it must be calculated twice. I wouldn't agree with that at all, but it would explain the different answers.

Comment: Is it possible the source has committed mistake in its solution? What's the standard procedure? Should optimization not be done while generating $3-$ address code?

Comment: It looks like a homework question. There are correct answers, there is your answer, and there’s the answer the teacher expects.